# How to guarantee that app contains no memory leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode4

How can one guarantee (or at least come reasonably close) that one's app contains no memory leaks?

What are the specific steps one should follow please?

I tried `Product -> Analyze`, which actually found a leak, however both before and after i fixed it `Product -> Profile -> Leaks`, none were shown.

In the image below, what should i be looking at? What is an indication of a leak?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruments finds leaks at runtime. You need click the "Record" button on left side of toolbar  to run.

Check [this link](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/) for more details on how to detect memory leaks with Instruments.

Comment: Right. I hit "Record", program ran, no Leaked Objects showed up

Comment: You might want to actually run all sections of your app to see what's wrong. A leak might happen after clicked a button or start a new view.